# Pandas read html table to dataframe cannot print

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get html table by using beautifulsoup like this.

```
alltable = bt.find_all('table')
print(alltable)
```

It show output like this.

```
[<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>User</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr valign="TOP">
<td><a href="/printers/PDF">PDF</a>-1 </td>
<td>Test </td>
<td>User1 </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="TOP">
<td><a href="/printers/PDF">PDF</a>-2 </td>
<td>Test </td>
<td>User1 </td>
</tr>

<tr valign="TOP">
<td><a href="/printers/PDF">PDF</a>-3 </td>
<td>Document1 </td>
<td>User1 </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>]
```

I read html table to dataframe and print like this.

```
df = pd.read_html(str(alltable))
print(df['Name'])
```

It show error like this.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Panda's read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of DataFrame objects - not a single DataFrame object. In your case, you need to index into the only element of the list:

```
>>> df[0]['Name']
0         Test
1         Test
2    Document1
Name: Name, dtype: object
```